# can i use google analytics 'numbers' to sorting posts?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, matomo

is it possible to use  **google analytics** or **piwik script** to show page visits 
and  sorting posts in the site according to this analytics

whithout write a php code to calculate visits from scratch

and is it possible to know what pages my visitor watching know at this time and calculate Top thread open at this time

just using **google analytics** or **piwik script** or if there is another good service

What do you advise me google analytics or self-hosted script piwik

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying [GAPI](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) which gives you data from Google Analytics in a simple PHP OO way.